# How to create a 2-dimension array for abstract class

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm trying to build a chess board of chess pieces. I got this

```
class ChessPiece 
{
public:
    ChessPiece();
    virtual ~ChessPiece();
    virtual bool movePiece() = 0;
};
```

and this class

```
class Pawn: public ChessPiece
{
public:
    Pawn();
    virtual ~Pawn();
    bool movePiece();
};
```

in my main i'm trying to create a 2-dimension array of ChessPiece, but because it's abstract it's giving me problems.

I tried this

```
ChessPiece** board = new ChessPiece[8][8];
```

or

```
ChessPiece*** board = new ChessPiece*[8];
```

but it don't seem to work..
any help will be greatly appreciated
Thank You!

Comment: `ChessPiece*** board = new ChessPiece*[8];` Hooray, you're a 3star programmer now. Congrats!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your board must hold pointers to `ChessPiece` with each piece allocated separately.  The board is always 8x8, so there's no reason to allocate it with `new`.  Instead:

```
ChessPiece * board[8][8];
```

Then something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    board[1][i] = new Pawn();
}
board[0][0] = new Rook();
board[0][1] = new Knight(); 
// etc...
```

*(**EDIT**: deleted an implementation using fixed-size arrays of each piece type, because it's possible for pawns to get promoted to other piece types.)*

Of course, you could arrange the data differently.  You should probably group all the game data into a `ChessGame` class or struct.  You might write a `PlayerPieces` class containing only one player's pieces, and then put 2 of them in `ChessGame`.  There are many possibilities -- ultimately it depends on your own style and preferences.

Comment: I can do that. but doesn't `new` allocate memory for it? What will happen if I send my board to another function? It will deleted when the scope is over?

Comment: Your programs should have well-defined ownership policies.  There's no reason why a function that takes your chess board as a parameter would delete it - pass it by pointer or reference.

Comment: May be I'm missing something, but the `new` and `delete` looks good, if the pieces are to be moved all over the board, not just initialization, isn't it ? +1 btw

Comment: Better may be `std::array<std::array<std::unique_ptr<ChessPiece>,8>,8> board;`

Comment: @P0W not needed, moving a piece is like:
    `board[row + 1][col] = board[row, col];  board[row][col] = nullptr;`
for example of advancing a pawn one space

Comment: `"...so there's no reason to use them."` There may be a reason to use dynamic structures if chess pieces occupy a lot of memory.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, if you decide to go with heap ownership, `unique_ptr` would be nice because you could move a piece and null its previous position in one step using `unique_ptr = std::move(unique_ptr)`.

Comment: @doc you are right, I left that out for brevity but I suppose correctness is more important.

Comment: @japreiss I have recalled a chess rule, which gives another reason to use dynamically allocate pieces. So called promotion, when pawn reaches end of the board (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotion_%28chess%29). :)

Comment: Oops, I thought that only allowed the player to recover a previously captured piece.  Well, that is a good reason to go the dynamic route.